# What is wrong with my if perl statement?

Tags: perl, if-statement

Ok this is driving me crazy!!

Looked at many examples and read up on if statements in perl and everything looks correct to me so can anyone else spot the error?

```
#Start of script
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

##########################
#### Define Variables ####
##########################
echo $PWD;
mainDirectory=$ENV{HOME}"/test/";
file='report.txt';
backupDirectory=$ENV{HOME}"/test/backup";
number_to_try=0;

##################################
#### Check if the file exists ####
################################## 
filename=$mainDirectory$file;
echo $filename;

if (-e $filename) {
    print "File Exists!"
}
```

error message I get is:

```
./perl.pl: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
./perl.pl: line 18: `if (-e $filename) {'
```

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: How is this perl ?

Comment: its a perl script i'm starting... #!/usr/bin/perl .. how is it not??

Comment: This is mainly written in `sh`, except for the conditional at the end and the `%ENV` hash. Using the wrong shebang does not magically fix this. Perl has no `echo`. Variables are assigned like `$foo = "$ENV{HOME}/test/";` (notice `$` sigil on the LHS)

Comment: You have a ton of variables without sigils (the little $ or @ marker), and you seem to be mixing php and perl functions and syntax.

Comment: You should be getting a lot more error messages than that. Most of it looks like valid sh/bash syntax, which is *not* valid Perl syntax. Perl has no built-in `echo` command. If `mainDirectory` is supposed to be a variable, it needs to be `$mainDirectory`. `$ENV{HOME}/"test/"` should be `"$ENV{HOME}/test/"`. And so on.

Comment: ok learn't something new from all this as well... the shebang HAS to be in the first line.. or it will just interpret it as sh.  Thanks for the constructive comments :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the lines above "if" are not valid Perl; I believe you wanted to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

##########################
#### Define Variables ####
##########################

my $mainDirectory = "$ENV{HOME}/test";
my $file = 'report.txt';
my $backupDirectory = "$ENV{HOME}/test/backup";
my $number_to_try = 0;

##################################
#### Check if the file exists ####
##################################

my $filename = "$mainDirectory/$file";
print "$filename\n";

if (-e $filename) {
        print "File Exists!\n";
}
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` is considered better than `-w ... use strict;`

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree, "use warnings" for this file only is way better than using "-w" program-wide and risk annoying any modules you use.  (I typically stamp out "-w" when I can.)

Comment: Brilliant reply thank you, also learn't something new from all this as well... the shebang HAS to be in the first line.. or it will just interpret it as sh. Thanks for the constructive comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go over some more tutorials on Perl basics, especially syntax.

Scalar variables should be prefixed with `$`.

When you concatenate strings, [use the `.` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators).

What is `$PWD`? [You can get the current directory using the `Cwd` module.](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)

What is `echo`? [Do you mean `print`?](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten with minimum change:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

##########################
#### Define Variables ####
##########################

#echo $PWD;
$mainDirectory=$ENV{HOME}."/test/";
$file='report.txt';
$backupDirectory=$ENV{HOME}."/test/backup";
$number_to_try=0;

##################################
#### Check if the file exists ####
################################## 
$filename=$mainDirectory.$file;
#echo $filename;

if (-e $filename) {
    print "File Exists!"
}
```

It is highly recommended to use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` though.

Comment: Semicolon after `print "File Exists!"`?

Comment: @rutter Trailing semicolons in a block are optional: `{ foo() }` is the same as `{ foo();;;;;}`

Comment: Perl will tolerate it if don't use `use strict` :)

Comment: Aha, right. One of the few cases where I'm pickier than the compiler!

Comment: @amon Although trailing semicolons are optional in blocks, I've found you are much less likely to make a mistake when adding additional lines if you always have a semicolon at the end of a (blocking-ending) statement.